# How to stop apt from uninstalling the packages while updating

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I using apt in terminal to install an update.
When i used `apt-get -f install` it showed

```
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 428 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5691kB of archives.
After this operation, 451MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I dont want to remove 428 packages. These are linked with other applications. (Some packages are Ruby1.8, Perl, python libraries and so on). How should i install the 7 packages without removing 428 packages.

Comment: What are those 7 packages?

Comment: You can try aptitude, and see if you can find a better dependency resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Then you'll need to look at what the dependencies are.

There is only one reason this would happen. You are explicitly requesting the install of a package that conflicts with a package that a large number of other packages depend on.

In other words, 428 packages depend on `libfoo`. Whatever you did is causing `libfoo` to be uninstalled, thus all of those other packages **must** be uninstalled.

$20 says you're mixing repositories between Ubuntu and something else, or you're mixing repositories for major release versions. Do you have some Debian, Mint or PPA sources?

Comment: Ya, I am mixing PPAs and Debians. How do i stop libfoo from getting uninstalled?

Comment: Using a system like `apt` package dependencies and conflicts **must** be resolved. The only way to not make this happen is to not do whatever you're trying to do. Your only *other* option is to use `dpkg` with `--force`, but that will likely leave you with something broken (and possibly an unusable system). Long story short: **don't do that**.

Answer (score 0):

Use apt-pin

http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

It may take a little time to figure out exactly what package has all of those dependencies, but if you pin it, the rest will stay.

You may find using aptitude to identify and pin them to be easier, though:

http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude

Answer (score -1):

you can enter
$ apt-get upgrade package1 package2 ..
where package1, package2 are all the packages which apt-get want remove.
if you have a long list, copy-paste the list to a file. join all lines of packages to remove and type before "apt-get upgrade ". save and execute the file:
$ . ./file